# Add x days to a DATE-field, where x is another column

Tags: mysql, sql, time, mysql-error-1064

I have a table which has a `DATE`-column, along with a `int` modifier column. I'd like to somehow be able to add `x` days  to the `DATE`-column, where `x` is the modifier's value.

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.dateField, DATE_ADD(t.dateField, t.dateModifierValue)
FROM fooTable t
```

However, that is obviously an invalid SQL-query.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| DateField  |  Modifier | Expected result |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| 2013-05-11 |     7     |    2013-05-18   |
| 2013-01-01 |     1     |    2013-01-02   |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Sure, this could be done using multiple queries, letting another language build up the query — but where would the fun be in that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SELECT t.dateField, DATE_ADD(t.dateField, INTERVAL t.dateModifierValue DAY) FROM fooTable t;

Comment: Wow. That was way too easy, can't believe I missed that. Many thanks!